# How to prevent allocations in unrollable code?

Tags: haskell

Given the following pieces of (boiled down and pseudo Haskell-ish) code:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

minimum3 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
minimum3 a b c | a < b     | a < c     = a
                           | otherwise = c
               | otherwise | b < c = b
                           | otherwise c

readMinimum3 :: V.Vector Double -> Int -> Double
readMinimum3 v i = do

    a <- V.unsafeRead v (i+0)
    b <- V.unsafeRead v (i+1)
    c <- V.unsafeRead v (i+2)

    -- manually unrolled version of:
    -- [a,b,c] <- sequence [V.unsafeRead v (i+j) | j <- [0..2]]

    return $! minimum3 a b c
```

`minimum3` is a standin for a bigger function `median15` but the idea is the same. All of this is done to prevent memory allocations, in fact this code gets compiled down to basically linear assembler.

I've also tried the same thing based on `vectors` hoping that fusion would eliminated the intermediate vector holding the read values, but no luck.

The question is if there is any way to write this in a more maintainable way without having to unroll the thing by hand?

Comment: Trying to get a declarative language to produce a certain lowlevel behaviour is generally a bad idea and contradicts the idea of "declarative programming". Maybe you could outsource the relevant operations to another language?

Comment: @Ctx true ... otoh the asm generated from the manually unrolled code is actually pretty decent. Once the exploration phase is over I don't mind having that in my code.

Comment: BTW, your code looks a bit funny: nested guards, monadic `do` while returning a pure type. Not a big deal, since the question is about optimization, but you might want to clarify that anyway.

Comment: Yep, that's probably more pseudo Haskell than real code :-)

Comment: @Ctx: Often it's easy to convince SQL, a poster child of declarative, to generate the plan you ask for, unless what you ark for something unreasonable. Also, isn't `do`-notation pretty "imperative", that is, a pretty linear, predictable nested function application?

Comment: @9000 But you usually cannot "convince" the database to follow a special plan within the sql-statement itself, but you have to make appropriate indexes, make sure the row statistics are accurete, set environment parameters etc. pp. Yes, the do-notation is a compromise being pure functional on one hand but pragmatic enough to resemble imperative programming up to some degree. If it is used extensively it is usually a strong indication that the wrong language was chosen ;)

Comment: @Ctx: Indeed! You can _hope_ to convince the implementation follow your understanding how to do something, but there's no guarantee. In other words, there are no tools for finer control, and often no visibility into the reasons why the compiler decides not to apply an "obvious" pattern. I wish both Haskell and SQL had more tools for that. Maybe you know some? (The problem is not endemic to functional / declarative realms; e.g. it's often hard to understand why C++ would not vectorize a certain "obviously parllel" computation.)

Comment: @9000 With PostgreSQL "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" is very useful to understand why the database does things a certain way (and this helps much to take appropriate countermeasures). Unfortunately I do not know an equivalent useful tool for haskell&friends...

Comment: @Ctx GHC Haskell internally compiler to Core, which can be dumped with `-ddump-simpl`. Sometimes it clarifies a lot, other times it can produce a hard to read code.

Comment: @Ctx [1/2] (1) Haskell libraries like *vector* offer tools explictly geared for writing fairly low-level Haskell code tuned for performance. It can get tricky sometimes, and the resulting code won't necessarily be very pretty or very "declarative", but depending on what you are trying to write it is very much a reasonable path to follow. (2) "If [do-notation] is used extensively it is usually a strong indication that the wrong language was chosen" -- That claim is too broad. do-notation is just syntactic sugar for monadic code, and monadic code is definitely not a code smell.

Comment: @Ctx [2/2] (3) As chi suggests, Core output (possibly paired with relevant time and memory profiles) can be seen as a rough counterpart to EXPLAIN ANALYZE in Haskell.

Comment: @duplode Maybe the claim is too general, but was meant as a reply to "do-notation being pretty imperative" and to better take an imperative language in the first place when it is used too much for that purpose. I do not deny that there may be sensible applications.

Comment: Your code would be subject to stream fusion if you wrote `minimum3`/`median15` taking a vector and then using a fold over it. [This paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/haskell-beats-C.pdf) goes into more detail about this sort of thing. The general advice is always the same: write your code using functions that fuse (like folds). `sequence` seems like a singularly bad idea in this case.

Comment: As I see it, this has nothing to do with vector in particular. You have a 'loop' over the integers `[0..2]` - it just so happens that the body of the loop uses `vector` operations and types. While fusion could certainly solve this problem, it isn't `vector` which would do it. If you represent your loop as `(Int, Int -> a)` (the size of the loop, and the body) then you could write a *term-level* Haskell program (as opposed to compiler-level, i.e. rewrite rules) which 'unrolls' such a loop, and use e.g. type classes to inline copies of the body. ....

Comment: ... While this is more tedious than using rewrite rules, it gives you a very fine-grained control over how you unroll your loop - unroll every iteration, or unroll `k` iterations into `n` blocks, or unroll up to `k` iterations for any given loop, etc.